# Fitting a quadratic function in python without numpy polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a quadratic function to some data, and I'm trying to do this without using numpy's polyfit function.

Mathematically I tried to follow this website https://neutrium.net/mathematics/least-squares-fitting-of-a-polynomial/ but somehow I don't think that I'm doing it right. If anyone could assist me that would be great, or If you could suggest another way to do it that would also be awesome.

What I've tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ones = np.ones(3)
A = np.array( ((0,1),(1,1),(2,1)))
xfeature = A.T[0]
squaredfeature = A.T[0] ** 2
b = np.array( (1,2,0), ndmin=2 ).T
b = b.reshape(3)

features = np.concatenate((np.vstack(ones), np.vstack(xfeature), np.vstack(squaredfeature)), axis = 1)
featuresc = features.copy()
print(features)
m_det = np.linalg.det(features)
print(m_det)
determinants = []
for i in range(3):
    featuresc.T[i] = b
    print(featuresc)
    det = np.linalg.det(featuresc)
    determinants.append(det)
    print(det)
    featuresc = features.copy()

determinants = determinants / m_det
print(determinants)
plt.scatter(A.T[0],b)
u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
plt.plot(u, u**2*determinants[2] + u*determinants[1] + determinants[0] )
p2 = np.polyfit(A.T[0],b,2)
plt.plot(u, np.polyval(p2,u), 'b--')
plt.show()
```

As you can see my curve doesn't compare well to nnumpy's polyfit curve.
[image: plot]

---

Update:
I went through my code and removed all the stupid mistakes and now it works, when I try to fit it over 3 points, but I have no idea how to fit over more than three points.
[image: updated]

This is the new code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ones = np.ones(3)
A = np.array( ((0,1),(1,1),(2,1)))
xfeature = A.T[0]
squaredfeature = A.T[0] ** 2
b = np.array( (1,2,0), ndmin=2 ).T
b = b.reshape(3)

features = np.concatenate((np.vstack(ones), np.vstack(xfeature), np.vstack(squaredfeature)), axis = 1)
featuresc = features.copy()
print(features)
m_det = np.linalg.det(features)
print(m_det)
determinants = []
for i in range(3):
    featuresc.T[i] = b
    print(featuresc)
    det = np.linalg.det(featuresc)
    determinants.append(det)
    print(det)
    featuresc = features.copy()

determinants = determinants / m_det
print(determinants)
plt.scatter(A.T[0],b)
u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
plt.plot(u, u**2*determinants[2] + u*determinants[1] + determinants[0] )
p2 = np.polyfit(A.T[0],b,2)
plt.plot(u, np.polyval(p2,u), 'r--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead using Cramer's Rule, actually solve the system using least squares.  Remember that Cramer's Rule will only work if the total number of points you have equals the desired order of polynomial plus 1. 
 If you don't have this, then Cramer's Rule will not work as you're trying to find an exact solution to the problem. If you have more points, the method is unsuitable as we will create an overdetermined system of equations.

To adapt this to more points, [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) would be a better fit as it solves the solution to the *Ax = b* by computing the vector *x* that minimizes the Euclidean norm using the matrix *A*.  Therefore, remove the `y` values from the last column of the features matrix and solve for the coefficients and use `numpy.linalg.lstsq` to solve for the coefficients:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ones = np.ones(4)
xfeature = np.asarray([0,1,2,3])
squaredfeature = xfeature ** 2
b = np.asarray([1,2,0,3])

features = np.concatenate((np.vstack(ones),np.vstack(xfeature),np.vstack(squaredfeature)), axis = 1) # Change - remove the y values

determinants = np.linalg.lstsq(features, b)[0] # Change - use least squares
plt.scatter(xfeature,b)
u = np.linspace(0,3,100)
plt.plot(u, u**2*determinants[2] + u*determinants[1] + determinants[0] )
plt.show()
```

I get this plot now, which matches what the dashed curve is in your graph, also matching what `numpy.polyfit` gives you:

[image: least squares fit]

Comment: Oh wow... I went back to my code and looked at my matrices, and thought to myself, this could work if I use exactly 3 points and voila it works. I come back here and read your answer and it says exactly what I just discovered. Thank you haha

Comment: @AhmadMoussa aha! My pleasure.  I figured you would have trouble if you were trying to add more points.  Least squares is the way to address this.  Glad I could help!

Comment: Odd how I couldn't find a single implementation online, where they don't use numpy's polyfit function...  (or maybe I didn't look hard enough)

Comment: The best description of least squares fitting, if you want to understand it as well as use it that I have found is in the book Digital Control of Dynamic Systems (3rd Edition) 3rd Edition
by Gene F. Franklin  (Author), J. David Powell  (Author), Michael L. Workman (Author)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will check it out.

Comment: @AhmadMoussa Yes that's quite odd.  There are a lot of solutions in MATLAB, but doing a quick search for Python doesn't seem to yield any fruitful results... but a good source on how to build the matrix to solve for this kind of problem is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#Matrix_form_and_calculation_of_estimates.  Building the pseudoinverse and solving for the solution is equivalent to finding the coefficients through least squares.  `numpy.linalg.lstsq` does this under the hood.

Comment: Also, as an interesting note, the coefficient matrix `features` in your code is known as the Vandermonde Matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: @user50619 Great textbook.  When I was studying digital control that was my go-to book.

Comment: @rayryeng I did read the wikipedia page, but seeing the linear analytic solution there, which I specifically was trying to avoid I didn't read much further. Also is it correct to call them features or not?

Comment: @AhmadMoussa yes it is perfectly acceptable. This is a modified version of Linear Regression often performed in machine learning and building a feature matrix is what is normally done. You're building a feature matrix.

Comment: @rayryeng Can you fit a polynomial to data using gradient descent, or only a line? How many ways are there to fit a function to data? This is so interesting!

Comment: @AhmadMoussa yes! Gradient descent finds the minimum of a cost function. If you actually expand out the matrix form of the problem to a sum of squared terms thus giving you your cost function, you can compute the gradient with respect to each parameter and thus iteratively solve for the coefficients. The cost function is convex so there will only be one unique minimum. There are not surprisingly many ways to fit a polynomial to data so long as the objective is to minimize some cost function. An example I can provide to you are genetic algorithms, methods coming from evolutionary learning.

Comment: @AhmadMoussa my pleasure! Also here's a good link using genetic algorithms for linear regression: “Genetic Algorithms” by Sagini Abenga https://link.medium.com/Gz1cugJ7KW. Genetic algorithms here can be very useful if you have a very large amount of data, which would be taxing to represent in memory. Link also has a Python implementation. Good luck!